# Exception in EDI Stream to Java Object conversion

Tags: java, edifact

I am trying to read an EDI Message and converting it to Java object ,but I am ended with below exception .

> Exception in thread "main" org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter
>   source.   at
>   org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:64)
>     at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:526)    at
>   org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)    at
>   org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:456)    at
>   org.milyn.edi.unedifact.d97a.D97AInterchangeFactory.fromUNEdifact(D97AInterchangeFactory.java:58)
>     at
>   org.milyn.edi.unedifact.d97a.D97AInterchangeFactory.fromUNEdifact(D97AInterchangeFactory.java:40)
>     at com.ibm.gpohub.edi.common.SmooksSample.main(SmooksSample.java:18)
>   Caused by: org.milyn.edisax.EDIParseException: EDI message processing
>   failed [ORDRSP][D:97A:UN].  Segment [FTX], field 4 (TEXT_LITERAL),
>   component 1 (Free_text_-_-1) expected to contain a value.  Currently
>   at segment number 6.  at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapComponent(EDIParser.java:687)   at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapField(EDIParser.java:636)   at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapFields(EDIParser.java:606)  at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapSegment(EDIParser.java:564)     at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapSegments(EDIParser.java:535)    at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapSegments(EDIParser.java:453)    at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.parse(EDIParser.java:428)  at
>   org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.parse(EDIParser.java:410)  at
>   org.milyn.edisax.unedifact.handlers.UNHHandler.process(UNHHandler.java:97)
>     at
>   org.milyn.edisax.unedifact.handlers.UNGHandler.process(UNGHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   org.milyn.edisax.unedifact.handlers.UNBHandler.process(UNBHandler.java:75)
>     at
>   org.milyn.edisax.unedifact.UNEdifactInterchangeParser.parse(UNEdifactInterchangeParser.java:113)
>     at
>   org.milyn.smooks.edi.unedifact.UNEdifactReader.parse(UNEdifactReader.java:75)
>     at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:76)    at
>   org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:86)
>     ... 7 more

Here is the code snippet:

```
 D97AInterchangeFactory d97InterChangeFactory   = (D97AInterchangeFactory)SmooksFactoryImpl.D97A_FACTORY.getInstance();
            InputStream ediSource = new FileInputStream("C:\\EDIFACT_MSG.txt");
            UNEdifactInterchange interchange = d97InterChangeFactory.fromUNEdifact(ediSource);
        if(interchange instanceof UNEdifactInterchange41){
            List<UNEdifactMessage41>  messages =  ((UNEdifactInterchange41) interchange).getMessages();
            for(UNEdifactMessage41 msg:messages){
                System.out.println(msg.toString());
            }
        }
```

EDIMessage :

> UNA:+.?
>   UNB+UNOC:3+662424795TEST:16+IBMEDIID:ZZ+160330:1416+IG-62779496
>   UNG+ORDRSP+662424795TEST:16+IBMEDIID:ZZ+160330:1420+FG-34160863+UN+D:97A
>   UNH+80534414+ORDRSP:D:97A:UN BGM+231+20160330+4
>   DTM+69:20150501150000UTC?+12:304 FTX+SSR+++:Blank FTX+AAR++ST
>   FTX+COI+++CLW FTX+PRI++8 FTX+DEL++06 FTX+CUR+++Pack all item into one
>   box FTX+DIN+++make a call to customer before delivery
>   FTX+PRD+++1:1:PC01 FTX+AAP+++900:accept RFF+PC:20AMS67000
>   RFF+SE:PC01K33E RFF+SZ:ND RFF+ABO:Y RFF+CO:IBM1234501
>   DTM+4:20150501010101UTC?+12:304 RFF+ACW:CASE_12345 RFF+ADG:Y RFF+ACH:Y
>   RFF+ZOD:order_desk01 RFF+ZSD:IBM RFF+ZPD:30006672 RFF+ZCS:Blank
>   RFF+ZZZ NAD+SE+30001234++IBM NAD+BY+US00000001++Coca Cola:CA+9/F:841
>   WEBSTER ST:stress 3:Blank+SAN FRANCISCO++94117+US CTA+PD+:Jordan
>   Surzyn COM+Minako@DHL.com:EM COM+6508624654:TE NAD+OY+US00000001++IBM
>   Field Service:CA+9/F:900 WEBSTER ST:stress 3:Blank+SAN
>   FRANCISCO++94117+US CTA+CR+:Will Smith COM+Will@ibm.com:EM
>   COM+6508624654:TE LIN+10 PIA+5+04X6076 IMD+F++:::KEYBOARD NetVista
>   Keyboard (USB) QTY+21:1:EA DTM+69:20160610120000UTC?+12:304
>   FTX+OSI+++INW FTX+LIN+++ZSP1 FTX+AAP+++900:Accept FTX+ZCT+++STO from
>   DC to FSL RFF+ZSB:01 RFF+ZRO:Y RFF+ZOR:KEYBOARD in good condition
>   RFF+ZST:SOFT UNS+S UNT+50+80534414 UNE+1+FG-34160863 UNZ+1+IG-62779496

Can anyone guide me , where I am doing wrong ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your whole project, I need to use it as well,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of the improper EDIFACT message format. It is resolved after I got the proper EDIFACT message, as shown below. Hope any one faced similar issue may help this . --thanks

> UNA:+.? '
>   UNB+UNOC:3+IBM:ZZZ+662424795TEST:16+160330:1416+00000016086706++++1'
>   UNG+ORDRSP+IBM:ZZZ+662424795TEST:16+160330:1420+00000000160867+UN+D:97A'
>   UNH+1+ORDRSP:D:97A:UN' BGM+231+20160330+4'
>   DTM+69:20160501150000UTC?+12:304' FTX+AAR++ER' FTX+SSR+++N:AM'
>   FTX+COI+++CLW' FTX+PRI++8' FTX+DEL++04' FTX+CUR+++Pack all item into
>   one box' FTX+DIN+++make a call to customer before delivery'
>   FTX+PRD+++IBMDECK001::PC01' FTX+AAP+++900:accept' RFF+PC:20AMS67000'
>   RFF+SE:PC01K33E' RFF+SZ:ND' RFF+ABO:N' RFF+CO:IBM1234501'
>   RFF+ACW:IBMCASE12301' DTM+4:20150501000000UTC?+12:304'
>   NAD+SE+30006672++3100001' NAD+BY+US00000001++CA:NEC Personal
>   Computers, Ltd.+9/F:841 WEBSTER ST:stress 3+SAN
>   FRANCISCO++941171717+US' CTA+PD+:Jordan Surzyn' COM+Minako@DHL.com:EM'
>   COM+6508624654:TE' NAD+OY+US00000001++CA:NEC Personal Computers,
>   Ltd.+9/F:841 WEBSTER ST:stress 3+SAN FRANCISCO++941171717+US'
>   CTA+CR+:Jordan Surzyn' COM+Minako@DHL.com:EM' COM+6508624654:TE'
>   LIN+20+++1:10' PIA+5+04X6076' IMD+F++:::KEYBOARD NetVista Keyboard
>   (USB)' QTY+21:1:EA' DTM+69:20160610120000UTC?+12:304' FTX+LIN+++ZSP1'
>   FTX+AAP+++900:Accpet' FTX+OSI+++INW' FTX+BSC+++KEYBOARD in good
>   condition' RFF+SE:Y' NAD+OY+01+SOFT' UNS+S' UNT+41+1'
>   UNE+1+00000000160867' UNZ+1+00000016086706'

Comment: Yes, the EDIFACT default segment terminator is the ' character, here as specified in the UNA segment.